# R - Combining two lists containing lists by name of list items

Tags: r

I want to combine two lists. Those lists contain list items which contain a data frame. For example

```
dfa1 = data.frame(a=1:3, b = letters[1:3])
dfa2 = data.frame(a=2:4, b = letters[1:3])
dfb1 = data.frame(a=3:6, b = letters[3:6])
dfb2 = data.frame(a=4:7, b = letters[3:6])

list1 <- list(a = list(part1 = dfa1), b = list(part1 = dfa2))
list2 <- list(a = list(part2 = dfb1), b = list(part2 = dfb2))
```

Now I want to combine `list1` and `list2` so that I have a new list with which contains the sublist `a` containing data frames part1 and part2. And so on (at the end i want to do this with a general number of data frames)

What I have so is

```
mapply(list1, list2, FUN=list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

This results in a list containing the sublists `a` and `b` containing the lists `[[1]]` containing `part1` and `[[2]]` containing `part2`. However, I want sublists `a` and `b` containing only `part1` and `part2` without `[[1]]` and so on.

Comment: Like `Map(c, list1, list2)` ?

Comment: Yes, perfect thanks